# aligning the footer text and the images correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is [the website](http://wix.com)

1. I'm issues aligning the images to the center of the box. The code

```css
.index_image{
  width: 70%;
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);    
}
.index_image img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row index_image">
<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/84770f_dec41f79f196959a09f9a7d88a507b86.jpg/v1/fill/w_266,h_85,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/84770f_dec41f79f196959a09f9a7d88a507b86.jpg" >
</div>
```

I think bootstrap row is pulling -15px to the left. And I don't know what to do about it, I tried all kinds of margin and I created a wrapper div and tried margin, nothing worked.

2. The copyright section of the footer is slightly higher than the Linkedin section. and I don't know what to do about it, they have to be aligned. This is caused by the font of course. applying padding or margin doesn't seem to help, nor `bottom: somevalue` and absolute positions don't work in bootstrap.

```css
.copyright{
  float: left;
  font: normal normal normal 12px/1.3em Arial,'ms pgothic',helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #616060;
    text-align: left; 
}
.linkedin{
  float: right;
  color: #043551;
  font: normal normal normal 20px Arial,'ms pgothic',helvetica,sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="row footer">
<div class="col-xs-6 copyright">
© 2016 company
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 linkedin">
 Follow us on <a someheref>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1** :
Give `margin: auto` to the image container. And it always better to give `display: block` to remove the small whitespace below the image.

```css
.index_image{
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);    
}
.index_image img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row index_image">
<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/84770f_dec41f79f196959a09f9a7d88a507b86.jpg/v1/fill/w_266,h_85,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/84770f_dec41f79f196959a09f9a7d88a507b86.jpg" >
</div>
```

**Issue 2** : 
Use `display: inline-block` for the footer and align using `vertical-align: top`.

```
.footer .copyright,
.footer .linkedin {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also don't forget to clear the `float`s.

```
.footer:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
.copyright {
  float: left;
  font: normal normal normal 12px/1.3em Arial, 'ms pgothic', helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #616060;
  text-align: left;
}
.linkedin {
  float: right;
  color: #043551;
  font: normal normal normal 20px Arial, 'ms pgothic', helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
}
/*clears float*/

.footer:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.footer .copyright,
.footer .linkedin {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="row footer">
  <div class="col-xs-6 copyright">
    © 2016 company
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 linkedin">
    Follow us on
    <a someheref>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing that you want

```css
.index_image{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  width: 70%;
  height: 20%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);    
}
.index_image img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  

}
```

```html
<div class="row index_image">
<div class="col-md-12 center" style="text-align: center">
<img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/84770f_dec41f79f196959a09f9a7d88a507b86.jpg/v1/fill/w_266,h_85,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/84770f_dec41f79f196959a09f9a7d88a507b86.jpg" >
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try margin-left: auto!important;
  margin-right: auto!important;

Comment: worked, before i accept the answer, do you have any idea what to do with the footer issue?

Comment: it will help you copyright{
padding-top:1%;
  float: left;
  font: normal normal normal 12px/1.3em Arial,'ms pgothic',helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #616060;
    text-align: left; 
}

Answer (score 1):

I think your first question has been answered, for the uneven footer links i would do this. This is assuming that your footer is in a container obviously.

```css
    .copyright{
      float: left;
      font: normal normal normal 12px/1.3em Arial,'ms pgothic',helvetica,sans-serif;
        color: #616060;
        text-align: left; 
position: relative;
padding-top: 100%;

    }
    .linkedin{
      float: right;
      color: #043551;
      font: normal normal normal 20px Arial,'ms pgothic',helvetica,sans-serif;
      text-align: right;
position: relative;
left: 100%;
padding-top: 98%;
    }
```

```html
    <div style="width:300px; height:10px;">
    <div class="col-xs-6 copyright">
    © 2016 company
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 linkedin">
     Follow us on <a someheref>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```